# Explicitly convert to nullable generic type

Tags: c#

I have a class with the following setup:

```
public class Cell
{
    readonly private string? _rawString;

    public Cell(string inpString)
    {
        this._rawString = inpString == "" ? null : inpString;
    }

    public static explicit operator DateTime(Cell cell)
    {
        DateTime date = DateTime.MinValue;
        if (DateTime.TryParseExact(cell._rawString, "yyyy/MM/dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out date))
        {
            return date;
        }

        else
        {
            throw new InvalidCastException($"Cannot convert {cell._rawString} to a date.");
        }
    }

    public static explicit operator DateTime?(Cell cell)
    {
        return cell._rawString is null ? null : (DateTime)cell;
    }

    public static explicit operator string(Cell cell)
    {
        return cell._rawString;
    }
}
```

I want to create a static method that will let me do the following:

```
string? stringFormat = Cell.ConvertType<string?>(cell)
DateTime? dateFormat = Cell.ConvertType<DateTime?>(cell)
```

I have tried the following but having issues due to because I cannot feed in a nullable type to the method call.

```
    public static T TryConvert<T>(Cell cell)
    {
        if (cell._rawString is null && typeof(T).IsClass) return default(T);
        if (typeof(T) == typeof(DateTime)) return (T)(object)(DateTime)cell;
        if (typeof(T) == typeof(Decimal)) return (T)(object)(Decimal)cell;
        if (typeof(T) == typeof(int)) return (T)(object)(int)cell;
        if (typeof(T) == typeof(string)) return (T)(object)(string)cell;
        // Add more cases for other types as needed
        throw new InvalidCastException($"Cannot convert {cell._rawString} to {typeof(T)}.");
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Nullable reference types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/nullable-references) and [nullable value types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/nullable-value-types) are quite different and are handled by runtime differently - nullable value types are actually represented by a separate type - [`Nullable<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.nullable-1?view=net-6.0). As a result of that for unconstrained (neither to `struct` nor to `class`) generic type parameter `T` - `T?` is handled differently for value types and reference types. From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/nullable-references#generics):

> - If the type argument for `T` is a reference type, `T?` references the corresponding nullable reference type. For example, if `T` is a `string`, then `T?` is a `string?`.
> - If the type argument for `T` is a value type, `T?` references the same value type, `T`. For example, if `T` is an `int`, the `T?` is also an `int`.
> - If the type argument for `T` is a nullable reference type, `T?` references that same nullable reference type. For example, if `T` is a `string?`, then `T?` is also a `string?`.
> - If the type argument for `T` is a nullable value type, `T?` references that same nullable value type. For example, if `T` is a `int?`, then `T?` is also a `int?`.

Also generic constraints are not a part of method signature.

There are several workarounds which allow to handle this restrictions/differences:

1. Create 2 different constrained methods:

   ```
   public static T? TryConvertValue<T>(Cell cell) where T : struct
   {
       return default;
   }

   public static T? TryConvert<T>(Cell cell) where T : class
   {
       return default;
   }
   ```
2. Use dummy ignored input parameter which will allow to create 2 overloads:

   ```
   public static T? TryConvert<T>(Cell cell, T? _ = default) where T : struct
   {
       return default;
   }

   public static T? TryConvert<T>(Cell cell, T? _ = default) where T : class
   {
       return default;
   }
   ```

Comment: I've done #1 many times in the past. I never thought to try #2. It's elegant at the call site, but not in the implementation... but the implementation is only done once.