# IEnumerable<T?> doesn't get converted to IEnumerable<T> in extension method

Tags: c#, extension-methods, ienumerable

I have the following extension methods:

```cs
public static IEnumerable<T?> From<T>(params T?[] values) {
    return values.AsEnumerable();
}

public static IEnumerable<T> WhereNonNull<T>(this IEnumerable<T?> enumerable)
{
    return enumerable.Where(x => x != null).Cast<T>();
}
```

I use it like this:

```cs
uint? parentId = ...;
int b = ...;
foreach(var boneId in CollectionUtils.From(parentId, (uint)b).WhereNonNull())
```

`parentId` is of type `uint?` and
I would expect `boneId` to be of type `uint` due to the `Cast<T>()`, but it actually is `uint?`.

Am I missing something?

Comment: I can't reproduce it: https://dotnetfiddle.net/v92C1z

Comment: @DmitryBychenko in your example you can call `boneId.HasValue()`, which shouldn't be the case for `uint`, should it?

Comment: @Ralidex: I've added direct check as well: `{boneId.GetType() == typeof(uint)} :: {boneId.GetType() == typeof(uint?)}`

Comment: this is a contradiction in my eyes. `HasValue` only exists on nullable types.

Comment: @DmitryBychenko That test is flawed, because calling `GetType()` on a `Nullable<T>` always gives you the type of `T` (since doing that causes the value to be boxed, and thus you get the type of the boxed value). [See for example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/GlYBM6).

Comment: Check out the duplicate. Also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77387482/2501279) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77304793/2501279) answers can be interesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve the desired behavior with the `struct` and `notnull` constraints.

See [Constraints on type parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/constraints-on-type-parameters) for details

For `uint?` change the `WhereNotNull` method to:

```cs
public static IEnumerable<T> WhereNonNull<T>(this IEnumerable<T?> enumerable)
    where T : struct
{
    return enumerable.Where(x => x != null).Cast<T>();
}
```

To support reference types as well also add

```cs
public static IEnumerable<T> WhereNonNull<T>(this IEnumerable<T?> enumerable)
    where T : notnull
{
    return enumerable.Where(x => x != null).Cast<T>();
}
```

It all comes down to the difference between [nullable value types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/nullable-value-types) (`Nullable<T>` or `T?` for structs) and [nullable reference types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/nullable-references) `T?` (like `object?`):

The `struct` constraint will make sure that `T` must be a non-nullable value type. So in this case `T?` means `Nullable<T>`

In `notnull` constraint that the value will be a non-nullable reference or non-nullable value type. The behavior of this method is the same as the version without constraints when there is no overload with `struct` constraint available. You would only need it if you want to support both `Nullable<T>` and nullable reference types at the same time.

Comment: Can you explain why I need the type constraint?
And I can either have struct or reference types. Not both

Comment: I tried :D hope it makes sense.

Comment: @Raildex check out the duplicate. In short - "because specification says so" (or "because it was designed this way")